# How to create a new form model on Yii?

Tags: php, yii, yii-cformmodel

I am just a stupid started to the yii and the whole mvc thing.
I wanted to know if it's possible to create a form, that will just send me an e-mail with all the fields filled. No database storage, no major rules.

I never had a problem using the pre-made models like the login and the contact form one. Those work fine. So now I am trying a test form to see if I can create an working model but It doesn't seem to work.

View:

```
<form name="testform" id="testform" action="/default/apply" method="POST">
<input type="text" value="" id="test1" name="test1" />
<input type="submit" name="test_sbm" id="test_sbm" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Model:

```
<?php


class ApplicationForm extends CFormModel {

public $test1;


public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('test1', 'required'),

    );
}

}
```

Default Controller:

```
public function actionApply() {
    $this->layout = "home";
    $this->pageTitle = "Apply Now";

    $applymodel = new ApplicationForm;


    if(isset($_POST['testform'])){
         $applymodel->attributes=$_POST['testform'];
         $to = 'myemail@myserver.com';
            $subject = 'Test Form';
            $message = $applymodel->test1;
            $headers = 'From: test@test.com' . " " .
                    'Reply-To: tesy@test.com' . " " .
                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }

   $this->render('apply', array('model' => $applymodel));
}
```

I am probably missing tons of stuff, but I've been researching and can't find my way to just get the form info.
If anybody can show me the right direction, I would appreciate.

I just want to get the form values and send them by e-mail, for now.
Thanks

Comment: what is the problem in the above code you're showing?

Comment: It does not send any e-mail or gets the input value.
I used the same kind of function on my contact form and it works (though it goes to a database) I am able to save the data and send my team an email with all the form data.
Now with this new model it does not work. I just want to be able to get all the form values and send it by email.

Comment: first of all change the name from `test1` to `testform[test1]`

Comment: Thank you, that is all I needed. I'm working in tons of projects at the same time, and I can deal with normal php jquery and ajax, but the whole MVC Yii thing it's completely new to me and those stupid detail pass by me. That's all I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your input element from

```
<input type="text" value="" id="test1" name="test1" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" value="" id="test1" name="testform[test1]" />
```